# Trouble Drawing SVG Bezier Curve with jsPDF

Tags: svg, bezier, jspdf

I have a Bezier curve defined in SVG that I'd like to draw using jsPDF. I haven't been able to get the curve to render correctly using jsPDF. **How do I draw the Bezier curve defined in the SVG below using jsPDF?**

The curve in SVG:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="192" version="1.1" height="288">
    <path fill="black" stroke="black" d="M19.0544,25.8288C24.2384,43.2816,22.3952,46.9968,18.7376,50.510400000000004" stroke-width="0" font=" 10pt Arial"></path>
</svg>
```

My attempt at the curve using jsPDF:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.lines([[24.2384, 43.2816, 22.3952, 46.9968, 18.7376, 50.5104]], null, null, [1, 1], 'FD');
```

What the SVG produces when rendered (left) and what my jsPDF code produces (right):

[image]
[image]

Comment: take note of `M...` vs. `m...`; your SVG coordinates are absolute, and I bet the jsPDF library takes relative coordinates instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the initial move reflected in your code.  According to my reading of the documentation, shouldn't this be something more like the following?

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.lines([[24.2384, 43.2816, 22.3952, 46.9968, 18.7376, 50.5104]], 19.0544,25.8288, [1, 1]);
```

**Update**

Didn't notice the docs say coords are relative (thanks Pomax), so try this.

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
var x = 19.0544;
var y = 25.8288;
doc.lines([[24.2384-x, 43.2816-y, 22.3952-x, 46.9968-y, 18.7376-x, 50.5104-y]], x,y, [1, 1]);
```

Comment: I tried something like you just described. Setting the x and y to reflect the initial move just offset the curve but don't fix what the curve looks like. You can see what I'm talking about by trying  
`var doc = new jsPDF(); doc.lines([[24.2384, 43.2816, 22.3952, 46.9968, 18.7376, 50.5104]], 19.0544,25.8288, [1, 1], 'FD');` at  
http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/

Comment: Mike Kamerman's comment above is correct.  All lines() coordinates are relative to the last line origin. You will need to subtract the initial x,y from your bezier coords.

Comment: This is it! I wasn't compensating for the coordinates being relative. Without factoring that in, setting x,y (method lines' 2nd & 3rd arguments) just offset where the curve was drawn.